# Cannot convert Generic Class to Generic Interface, why?

Tags: c#, inheritance, repository

I have an IRepository interface that inherits from `IRepository<TObject>`. I also have a SqlRepository class that inherits from S`QLRepository<TObject>`, which in turn implements `IRepository<TObject>`. Why can't I instantiate a instance of SqlRepository as an IRepository?

```
public class MyObject : IObject {
    ...
}

public interface IRepository<TObject> where TObject : IObject, new() {
    ...
}

public interface IRepository : IRepository<MyObject> { }

public class SqlRepository<TObject> : IRepository<TObject> where TObject : IObject, new() {
    ...
}

public class SqlRepository : SqlRepository<MyObject> { }

public class Controller {
    private IRepository _repository;

    public Controller() {
        _repository = new SqlRepository();
    }
}
```

The example above fails when trying to assign a new SqlRepository to _repository in the Controller class, with the following error message.

```
Argument '1': cannot convert from 'SqlRepository' to 'IRepository'
```

Which basic principle of inheritance have I failed to grasp, please help.

Comment: I resolved the issue by making SqlRespository implement IRepository (public class SqlRepository : SqlRepository<MyObject>, IRepository { }), which seems a little superfluous but I guess I understand the logic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `IRepository` is an `IRepository<MyObject>` and not the other way around.

Basically:

`SqlRepository` is a `SqlRepository<MyObject>`
which is an `IRepository<MyObject>`.
To make that work, you should either inherit `IRepository<TObject>` from `IRepository` or make `SqlRepository` implement `IRepository` depending in your intention.

This issue is not generics-specific at all. Assume:

```
interface IMovable { }
interface IDrivable : IMovable { } 
class Ball : IMovable { }
```

It's obvious that `Ball` is not an `IDrivable` while it is an `IMovable`.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlRepository` implements `IRepository<T>`, not `IRepository`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare it like this:

```
private IRepository<MyObject> _repository;
```

Answer (score 0):

SqlRepository does not directly inherit from `IRepository`, it inherits from `IRepository<MyObject>`.

Try having `SqlRepository` inherit directly from `IRepository`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass generic types as well.

public class SqlObjectRepository : SqlRepository { ... }

But I don't think you can do that on the fly. It needs to be part of the definition of the object.