# Cannot convert from class to generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, contravariance

**EDIT: Updated to include actual code.**

I am having an issue with some custom generic interfaces and I am not entirely sure what to do. The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot convert from `Map` to `IMap<ICell>`

That error pops up when I try to pass `Map` as a parameter to a method that accepts `IMap<ICell>`. I have pasted sample code below. Just to be clear, `FieldOfView` doesn't use anything that hasn't been defined in `ICell` or `IMap`.

```
public class Map : IMap<Cell>
{
    private FieldOfView _fieldOfView;
    public int Width { get; }
    public int Height { get; }
    public Map(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        _fieldOfView = new FieldOfView(this as IMap<ICell>);
        _fieldOfView = new FieldOfView((IMap<ICell>)this);
    }
    public IEnumerable<Cell> GetAllCells()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                yield return GetCell(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
    public Cell GetCell(int x, int y)
    {
        return new Cell(x, y);
    }
    public void Copy(IMap<Cell> sourceMap)
    {
        // ...
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var cell in GetAllCells())
        {
            sb.Append(cell.ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public interface IMap<T> where T : ICell
{
    int Width { get; }
    int Height { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> GetAllCells();
    T GetCell(int x, int y);
    void Copy(IMap<T> sourceMap);
}

public class Cell : ICell
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public Cell(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = Y;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "overloaded";
    }
}

public interface ICell
{
    int X { get; }
    int Y { get; }
}

public class FieldOfView
{
    private readonly IMap<ICell> _map;
    public FieldOfView(IMap<ICell> map)
    {
        _map = map;
    }
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        foreach (var cell in _map.GetAllCells())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is similar to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088845/cannot-convert-generic-class-to-generic-interface-why), but a little different. I tried implementing an interface `IMap` as well as `IMap<T> : IMap where T : ICell`, but am having issues with that as well.

Lastly, I'm not sure if this is solvable with co/contravariance, but I am using C#3.0 so that is out of the picture for me (unless switching versions is the only way).

---

<strike>I think it would be fine with an implicit / direct cast?</strike>

```
_fieldOfView = new FieldOfView(this as IMap<ICell>); // or
_fieldOfView = new FieldOfView((IMap<ICell>)this);
```

But if there is a better way, I would like to do that. Resharper does throw me a warning when I cast `Map` to `IMap<ICell>` saying:

> Suspicious cast: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both `Map` and `IMap<ICell>`.

**EDIT2: Look's like neither of the casts worked.** I've decided instead to make Map be derived from IMap and just create the Cell objects where needed in the code.

Thanks @Rob and @MK87 for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*No*, `IMap<Cell>` is *not* the same as `IMap<ICell>`, so this line:

```
_fieldOfView = new FieldOfView(this as IMap<ICell>);
```

will always pass *null* as parameter.

*Yes*, this is definitely solvable with **variance**.

For example, you can have:

```
IEnumerable<object> list = new List<string>();
```

since `list` is `IEnumerable<`**`out`**`T>`, that means that every `IEnumerable<TT>` with `TT` that derives from `T` is a valid value for `list`. So the `List` doesn't have to be of `object`, it can be of any derived type.

But because you can't use variance, we need another hack.

**Possible solution: instead of deriving `Map` from `IMap<Cell>`, derive it from `IMap<ICell>`**. You'll have only to correct some points, for example the return type of `GetCell()` must become `ICell` instead of `Cell`. Is it feasable for you?

Comment: PS: Microsoft is already thinking about C# 7.0... And you're working with 3.0... Maybe the time has come for you to upgrade you C# version...

Comment: Haha, good point. It's not my project though - I'm updating an older open source project. There are a couple other places where some of the newer C# features would be useful so I'll drop a pull request and see what happens.

As far as deriving `Map` from `IMap<ICell>` is concerned, I could do that, and just create the `Cell` objects where needed. That looks to be the only way to keep the existing functionality. Thanks @MK87